# CultureInfo in Settings.Designer

Tags: c#, localization

Maybe I'm doing it wrong. But what i need.
i have 2 culture in my App
I want to choose the language in the settings and add next code:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
    {
        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        private static List<CultureInfo> nclacCultureInfos = new List<CultureInfo>()
        {
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"),
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        };

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSetting()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        [Category("Main Settings")]
        [DisplayName("Default Language")]
        public CultureInfo CurentLanguage
        {
            get
            {
                return ((CultureInfo)(this["CurentLanguage"]));
            }
            set
            {
                this["CurentLanguage"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I cant link nclacCultureInfos list and setting CurentLanguage. Need to browse only 2 culture in dropdown list in propertygrid and ideally it will be CultureInfo.Name like Russian, English. But at this moment  application displays all possible cultures in system. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a custom UITypeEditor.

```
public class CultureInfoEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private static List<CultureInfo> nclacCultureInfos = new List<CultureInfo>()
    {
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"),
        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
    };

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    IWindowsFormsEditorService currentService;

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        currentService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)
            provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        ListBox cultures = new ListBox();
        cultures.Items.Add(nclacCultureInfos[0].DisplayName);
        cultures.Items.Add(nclacCultureInfos[1].DisplayName);
        cultures.Text = ((CultureInfo)(context.Instance as Settings)["CurentLanguage"]).DisplayName;
        cultures.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        cultures.MouseClick += cultures_MouseClick;
        currentService.DropDownControl(cultures);

        return nclacCultureInfos[cultures.SelectedIndex];
    }

    void cultures_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentService.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

And should specify this editor for our property:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSetting()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
[Category("Main Settings")]
[DisplayName("Default Language")]
[Editor(typeof(CultureInfoEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))] // THIS LINE HAS BEEN ADDED
public CultureInfo CurentLanguage
{
    get
    {
        return ((CultureInfo)(this["CurentLanguage"]));
    }
    set
    {
        this["CurentLanguage"] = value;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.